# Read a string with part of string in newline using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to read a string from a an xml file and need to compare that string with the key from excel file

Key in the excel file is given below.Please note that part of string is in the new line

```
GID 
    avg checkers-checksum.
```

i want to represent the same string in an xml file and read that string using the powershell script.

i tried to represent the value in xml file using following sysntax

```
<GID1 value="GID`n      avg checkers-checksum"/>
```

i tried to compare the value read from xml file using following powershell command, but it didn't work

```
if($excelkey.Equals($xmlkey))
{
 return true
}
```

i also tried by giving the following value for xml but that also did not work

```
<GID1 value="GID'`n'      avg checkers-checksum"/>
<GID1 value="GID
      avg checkers-checksum"/>
```

How can i represent the string with newline to read using xml

Answer (score 0):

It's not usual to have white space in XML attributes.

Have you tried using a element instead, to preserve the whitespace use a CDATA section, or you can use the

e.g.

```
<GID1><![CDATA[GID
      avg checkers-checksum]]></GID1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The new line character could be `` `r ``, try

```
$excelkey.Contains("`r")
```

to verify whether your cell contains `` `r `` or any other special char.